# How to correctly use Scanner to print output stream

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using Scanner to take in input and print output but ln.nextLine() jumps to next line to scan.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");
           String line = null;
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                line = in.nextLine();

                if (line.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
                    break;
                }  else {
                    System.out.println("number entered 
                      "+Integer.parseInt(line));
                }

                System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");

        }
```

**This produces a output like:**
ENTER ID:
78
number entered 78
ENTER ID:
89
number entered 89

**Desired output is:**
ENTER ID:  78
number entered 78
ENTER ID:  89
number entered 89

what part of println sequence should I change to achieve this?

Comment: Change `System.out.println("ENTER ID: ");` to `System.out.print("ENTER ID: ");`

Comment: I have tried that but I think the issue lies with the how scanner works looks like line = in.nextLine(); moves the cursor to next line to take input

Answer (score -1):

System.out.println("...") method prints the string "..." and moves the cursor to a new line. The System.out.print("...") method instead prints only the string "...", without moving the cursor to a new line.

You need to change the System.out.println method call to System.out.print method call.